# Cardinality of the image of injection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, cardinals

**Claim**: Let $f: S \to T$ be an injection and $A$ be a finite subset of $S$. Then,
$$
|f[A]| = |A|
$$
that is, there is a bijection from $f[A]$ onto $A$.

[ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_Image_of_Injection) proves this fact using mathematical induction (MI). But does it really need MI?

Since $f$ is injective, we can simply define $g: A \to f[A]$ such that $\forall x \in A: g(x) = f(x)$. $g$ is bijective, hence, the claim follows directly.

Is there something I am missing?

I thought the set $A$ even need not be finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
$
The question was caused by confusion about the notation. We denote the cardinality of finite sets as
$$
A \text{ is finite}
\Leftrightarrow
\exists n \in \N: |A| = n
$$
But we also use $|\cdot|$ and $=$, $ \le$, and $\ge$ to compare the cardinality of sets, e.g., $|A| = |I_n|$ if there is a bijection between $A$ and the initial segment $I_n = \{i \in \N: i \le n\}$.

In the OP, I thought $|f[A]| = |A|$ is denoted by the latter definition. But I eventually found that the proposition actually says that for an injection $f: S \to T$, using the latter definition,
$$
\forall n \in \N: \forall A \subseteq X: [|A| = |I_{n}| \Rightarrow |f[A]| = |I_{n}|]
$$
or equivalently, according to the former definition,
$$
\forall n \in \N: \forall A \subseteq X: [|A| = n \Rightarrow |f[A]| = n]
$$
which requires MI to prove.